# Show the centraliser is a subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra

The centraliser $C_G(x)$ of $x \in G $ is $$C_G(x)={g \in G: xg=gx}$$
How do I show that this is a subgroup of G?

Comment: Show that both  $\;1\in C_G(x)\;,\;\;a,b\in C_G(x)\implies ab^{-1}\in C_G(x)\;$

Comment: In other words, how do you usually prove some subset of a group is a subgroup? The method you usually use, should work here, too.